# How to set focus to a textbox in a jquery dialog window?

Tags: jquery, focus, modal-dialog

Is there a way to set focus to an input textbox inside jquery dialog window? I have looked at some other question over here but could not find the answser.

I have tried ..

```
, open: function() { $(this).find("#inp").focus(); }
```

but it didn't work.

Any ideas? Thanks.

**UPDATE**

the content of dialog window is fetched thru an ajax call.

Comment: first of all test whether your `open` function executes

Comment: Yes checked in FF,IE,Crome. it does..

Comment: would you please post more scripts including load function...that will make easier to answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$("#inp").focus();
```

But if you are loading the dialog content with AJAX then you should put focus in call back function

```
$('#result').load('ajax/test.html', function() {
  $("#inp").focus();
});
```

Comment: I am using load() function to load the content.

Comment: Brilliant.. this has done the trick. I just tested in the FF, Chrome, and IE and it sets the focus. But as I was positioning the dialog to x and y of where user clicked, it fails this in IE because of this focus?

Comment: can you give codes how you position the dialog and also which version of IE?

Answer (score 0):

So, your open function works, right? Have you checked if it finds #inp? Just do

```
console.log($('#inp'));
```

And see if the element is actually there at the time focus() is being called. If it is not, then maybe the DOM wasn't finished being constructed (I'm assuming, your open() function is called from within said Ajax call's callback, right?).

The 'success' and 'error' Ajax-callbacks are being called after the call has finished, but not necessarily after all resulting DOM-manipulations are finished. One (slightly hacky) way I solved this in the was by delaying the focus for a few milliseconds:

```
setTimeout(function () {
    $(this).find("#inp").focus();
}, 50);
```

This gives the DOM a bit of time to put #inp in place.